# <label> button won't work with input type=file in CHROME

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, label

So I have this code:

```
echo "<label for=\"uploadImg\">";
echo "<input type=\"button\" id=\"uploadButton\" value=\"Replace Image\">";
echo "</label>";
echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"fileToUpload\" id=\"uploadImg\" />";
```

The css for it:

```
    .editBox input[type=file]
    {
        display: none;
    }
    #uploadButton
    {
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0 0 30px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
```

The button operates correctly in Firefox but in Chrome it won't work. If I replace the button with text(let's say the word "upload") it triggers the input=file right away.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: for starters, label end tag should be before input: echo "<label for=\"uploadImg\"></label>";

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a submit:

```
echo "<label for=\"uploadImg\"></label>";
echo "<input type=\"file\" name=\"fileToUpload\" id=\"uploadImg\" />";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"uploadButton\" value=\"Replace Image\">";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but changing the value to "submit" doesn't change anything.

Comment: You must not have a form tag around all 3 elements

Comment: Actually I do have a form tag around all of them.